# Catching 550 5.1.1 RESOLVER.ADR.RecipNotFound errors when sending email via System.Net.Mail

Tags: c#, system.net.mail

I am using Sytem.Net.Mail to send email via an Exchange server (on a different machine) through a web application in C#.  (Note that *each customer* will have the ability to set the smtp configuration, so they may not use Exchange.)

When sending the email, it is *not* throwing an exception if a message is sent to an undeliverable address.  Exchange *does* send me an email telling it the message was not sent.

Here's the message:

```
Diagnostic information for administrators:

Generating server: (exchange server)

(wrong address)
#550 5.1.1 RESOLVER.ADR.RecipNotFound; not found ##

Original message headers:

Received: from (webserver) by (exchangeserver) with Microsoft SMTP Server id (blah); Fri, 11 Jan 2013 10:16:02 -0500
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: (me)
To: (wrong address)
Date: Fri, 11 Jan 2013 10:16:02 -0500
Subject: (blah)
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Message-ID: (blah)
Return-Path: (me)
```

Is this because of a configuration setting on the exchange server?  Is there another way to catch this (maybe if I sent the mail asynchronously), or I am not able to find out if the message failed?

Note that as a requirement, I must send a separate email to each recipient.  So there is a for loop that sends an email to each address.  For addresses that are invalid, there is no exception caught, so the system thinks the email was sent successfully.

SendEmailError is a class that just holds error information.  WHat ends up being returned is a List with no items.  When sending a message to an invalid address, the code is not going into either of the two catch blocks.

Code:

```
public List<SendEmailError> SendEmail(MailAddress fromAddress, string subject, string body, bool isBodyHTML, MailPriority priority,
                            IEnumerable<MailAddress> toAddresses)
{
    List<SendEmailError> detectedErrors;

    // create the email message
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage()
    {
        Subject = subject,
        SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
        Body = body,
        BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
        IsBodyHtml = isBodyHTML,
        Priority = priority,
        From = fromAddress
    };

    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("myexchangeserver", 25)
    {
        Credentials  = new NetworkCredential("myid", "mypword", "mydomain");
    };

    foreach (MailAddress toAddress in toAddresses)
    {
        message.To.Clear();
        message.To.Add(toAddress);
        try
        {
            smtpClient.Send(message);
        }
        catch (SmtpFailedRecipientsException ex)
        {
            // if the error was related to the send failing for a specific recipient, log
            // that error and continue.
            SendEmailError error = new SendEmailError();
            error.Type = SendEmailError.ErrorType.SendingError;
            error.Exception = ex;
            detectedErrors.Add(error);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // if the error wasn't related to a specific recipient. add
            // an error and stop processing.
            SendEmailError error = new SendEmailError();
            error.Type = SendEmailError.ErrorType.ConnectionError;
            error.Exception = ex;
            detectedErrors.Add(error);
            break;
        }
    }

    return detectedErrors;
}
```

Comment: Scott have you been able to successfully send at least 1 email say for example to yourself..?

Comment: Yes, it sends emails fine.  It will send emails to valid addresses.  Exchange will also send me an email when an invalid address is used.  But I can't seem to catch an exceptions in code when an invalid address is used.

Comment: if you are enabling SSL shouldn't the port be `465`

Comment: if the email is not send you should be able to log that exception where is your code in the catch{} why are you putting a break inside the second catch{} ? also this line `message.To.Clear();` is it even sending email with a message you seem to be clearing it.. I might be missing something here..

Comment: I am using the company's internal exchange server and port 465 does not work.  Port 25 does.  And actually it works whether Use SSL is on or off.  I'll change the code to reflect that it's off :)

Comment: Scott to make things easier to read can you paste the full method that this code is in.. it appears you are doing something incorrectly but I can't tell because you don't show the full method signature / code

Comment: I've edited for the nitty gritty.  What I was excepting was that when the email address being sent to was an invalid address that it would fall into the `catch (SmtpFailedRecipientsException ex)` block.  However, it's not falling into either that or the `catch (Exception ex)` block.  As far as I can tell, no exception is thrown from Send() at all.  Is `Send()` asynch by default?  Should I be add a handler for the `SendComplete` event?  I assumed `Send()` was synchronous and `SendAsync()` was not,

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22595/discussion-between-dj-kraze-and-scott-korin)

Comment: you can see this site as well it will explain how you can try to get status of emails that failed in the catch{} block http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpfailedrecipientsexception.aspx

Comment: one more question.. are you wanting to send the emails to a group of recipients or one by one..? if they are the same messages that need to go to a group of recipients then you are doing this wrong in regards to your for loop you would probably want to build the sendto list and append a ";" at the end of the emails.. I have done something like this many times but I can't tell what your true intentions are.. please clarify

Comment: Apparently I'm not the only one this happens to:  http://forums.asp.net/t/1496313.aspx/1

Comment: The requirement for the function is that is sends to each address separately.

Comment: if you are to send it separately.. then I am confused by your for loop then.. what you need to do is passing a list of email recipients then in the for loop you would assign the sendTo email address based on each email address iteration , from there once you call the send method you should be able to track if sent or not.. if the email can't be sent then continue the loop after capturing the error

Comment: I have found several stackoverflow questions that appear to have the same problem. I do.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256382/email-send-failure, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239881/get-sent-mail-error